# What are the different mechanisms used by NodeJS to load modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I heard that Node.js uses three different mechanisms to load modules but don’t have an idea about what are they. Looking for expert opinion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may be little bit helpful https://medium.com/maxkimambo/how-does-node-module-loading-actually-work-8aa63849f5ae

Comment: I've not come across any such saying ("3 mechanism") as such, but the official documentation lists a few ways: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html